# Debian 7.0 failed to install package php5-dev

Tags: php, debian-installer

While trying to install in debian, shows `libssl-dev` dependency needed

> apt-get install php5-dev

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Installing `libssl-dev` package needed dependency `zlib1g-dev`.
Installing `zliblg-dev` package have unment dependencies,

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3) but 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13 is to be installed
```

How do install `zlib1g-dev` package to install `dev5-php`?

Comment: Try with  _aptitude_ to install libssl-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the below lines in the repository file:`/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
```

After update: `apt-get update` with the above added lines, I could able to install the `php5-dev` package successfully!

Answer (score 2):

You can install it by typing:

```
su -c 'aptitude install libssl-dev'
```

If not done please share output of

```
apt-cache show libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Post your texts from directory: `/etc/apt/sources.list` to see if the repository list would suffice or not.
See the  [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa),  this may be worth seeing.